# Python type checking: Require instance variable type annotation

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing, typechecking

Is there any way to warn on an undeclared type of an instance variable in mypy or with any other tool? For example:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
```

This first instance doesn't annotate the instance variable name, where I'd like a warning or something recommending the following style:

```
class Employee:
    name: str
    def _init__(self, name: str) ->  None:
        self.name = name
```

I'm using python3.8 right now with mypy 0.942, though that can change if it's supported in a different version.

Comment: i believe `self.name` is still typed as `str` in both cases. Also bear in mind that afaict, using `name: str` at the class level actually means something different - it make `name` a _class_ attribute, which you then override on an instance level in `__init__`

Comment: I was under the impression that `name` is still an instance attribute in the second case due to the lack of assignment. If I were to write `name: str = "default"` I'd end up with a class attribute, however. See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class_basics.html

Because name becomes an instance variable, I'd like to enforce instance variable typing on the same level as class variables are declared. AFAICT I can't enforce this but was hoping someone had an idea (or tell me that it's not possible!)

Comment: tbh I'm not certain about what I said